# In the absence of copy elision, is the copy/move constructor guaranteed to be called before the destructor?

Tags: c++, semantics

Pretty much what the title says. Consider this example:

```
MyClass func()
{
    MyClass myInstance;
    return myInstance;
}

int main()
{
    auto myInstance = func();
}
```

In the absence of copy elision, is the copy or move constructor of `MyClass` guaranteed to be called before the destructor as the call to `func()` returns `myInstance`? I imagine a class like `std::shared_ptr` would make use of such a property when returned by value.

Also, are there any pitfalls to relying on this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

From [stmt.return]/3:

> The copy-initialization of the returned entity is sequenced before the destruction of temporaries at the end
>   of the full-expression established by the operand of the return statement, which, in turn, is sequenced before
>   the destruction of local variables (6.6) of the block enclosing the return statement.